# Queue return elements in Nth position

Tags: java

Suppose I have a `list(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)`

I already have my `queue`class.

I want the result as `1,3,5,0,2,4,6` (the item at nth position is attached to the end of the original `queue`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Queue a=new Queue();
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    a.enter(i);
  }
Queue temp=new Queue();`

while(!a.isEmpty()){
  temp.enter(a.leave());//put the first element in temp
  System.out.print(a.leave()+" ");//print out the second one
  a.enter(temp.leave());//put the first element at the end of original queue
}
```

So My idea is to store the item that `leave` in `temp` then enter back.
No matter how I try this, it cannot give me the correct result. And its a infinite loop.

`leave()` remove the first item and return it.
`enter()` put the element at the end of queue

OK I've solved the problem. 
I should do like:

`while(!a.isEmpty()){
      a.enter(a.leave());
      System.out.print(a.leave()+" ");
     }`

Then it will give me the correct result.

Thanks guys for the effort, and sorry if anything in this problem is unclear. I'm still new to this :)

Comment: I don't understand how you get your output from your input, especially as you haven't stated n.

Comment: What is circle? Queue interface in java doesn't have `enter()` or `leave()` methods.

Comment: As it stands, this question is not at all clear. Please add more information to indicate what you're trying to achieve and what problem you're having.

Comment: I've already edited it.

Comment: Does `leave` actually *remove* the item from the queue, or just *retrieve* it?

Comment: remove the item and return the number

Comment: If that's the case, then you can't have an infinite loop.  On every iteration, two items are removed from `a`, and one is put back.  So after `a.length` iterations, `a` should be empty.  I suspect that you have an error in your `Queue` class.  You should show us that code, as well.

Comment: The question is pretty confusing, please show the Queue class code and give more a detailed explanation about how '0,1,2,3,4,5,6' becomes '1,3,5,0,2,4,6'. What rules determine the new order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start by warning you that this is a lousy answer that does not actually solve your problem, because I can't figure out what your goal is.  It *does*, however, explain the infinite loop you've encountered.

The infinite loop is the `while`, which waits for `Queue a` to be empty, which will *never* happen (unless `a` was already empty when the `while` loop started).

Each iteration through your `while` loop de-queues two items from `a`, and then en-queues the first item.  Even if this is what you intended for most of the iterations (I honestly can't tell), it fails for what should have been the last one.

When `a` is down to just one element, your `while` loop starts repeating this useless behavior forever:

1. Remove the one and only element from `Queue a`.
2. Remove *another* element from the now-empty `a`... somehow.
3. Print God-knows-what, followed by a space.
4. Put that "one and only" element (the one that actually existed) right back onto `a`.
5. Test if `a` is empty, which --- surprise --- it is not.
6. Go to 1.
7. Heat-Death of the Universe.

Once `Queue a` gets caught in this trap, it will "always" contain that last element.  The brief moments during which it *is* empty will occur only in the middle of the `while` block, and never during the iteration test at the *top* of that same block.

**Other Weirdness**

I came up with these questions while typing this answer.  They are questions you should ask *yourself*:

- What is the *goal* of your program?  (This will be required for almost any Stack Overflow questions you ask in the future.  Its near-absence from *this* question is why you've received such an incomplete answer.)
- What happens when you call `leave` on an empty `Queue`?  (Your `while` loop does this forever.)  Why is that the obviously correct thing to do?  What are the alternatives, and why are they obviously incorrect?
- What is `Queue temp` for?  It never has more than one item in it, so why can't it be replaced with a local variable?
- Why do you print the items you throw away?  Alternatively:  Why do you throw away the items you print?  Is printing them to the console something you wanted to do at all?
- What does *any* of this have to do with the "Nth position" in your title?

For future questions, I suggest you review the Help Center's "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and the links at the bottom of that article, especially Eric Lippert's "[How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".  I suspect your code could benefit a lot from the latter's "Rubber Duck Debugging":

> Explain to the duck using simple words why each line of each method in your program is obviously correct. At some point you will be unable to do so, either because you don't understand the method you wrote, or because it's wrong, or both. Concentrate your efforts on that method; *that's probably where the bug is*.

The duck would have caught many of these, I think.

Comment: My suspicion is that this is a class assignment, and the actual goal of the assignment is to enqueue `0,1,2,3,4,5,6` and then, using queue operations, make it print `1,3,5,0,2,4,6`, which is why the asker is throwing away the items they've printed -- they're done with them now.

Comment: This is a lab practice problem. I've solved it. Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

the methods used in the program doesn't exist i believe i.e  .leave()

but to get the element from any position using queues then you can use this

here n is the required position-1

for example if you need to print out element which is at position 5
n = 5-1, i.e 4
cause it follows indexing.

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
     queue.remove();
}
System.out.print(queue.peek());
```